# Spring MVC application filtering HTML in URL - Is this a security issue?

Tags: java, spring, security, http, spring-mvc

My existing Spring Web MVC application has the following handler mapping in the Controller.

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/welcome")
```

I trigger the following request`http://www.example.com/welcome`and this works fine.

The problem is

```
http://www.example.com/welcome.check.blah
```

also works!!!

Also, a HTTP GET request URL to the application with script tag is getting redisplayed though it fails the authorization.

Example `http://www.example.com/welcome<script>alert("hi")</script>` gets redisplayed as such in the browser window and as a result of my authorization logic "Not authorized" message is displayed.

I wonder if this is a security issue and should I need do any encoding/filtering in the code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This behavior is due to the option `useSuffixPatternMatch` which is true by default inside the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` (I assume you use Spring MVC 3.1).

> **useSuffixPatternMatch :**
>   Whether to use suffix pattern match (".*") when matching patterns to requests. If enabled a method mapped to "/users" also matches to "/users.*". The default value is "true".

To set `useSuffixPatternMatch` to *false*, the easiest way is to use `@Configuration` :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Api extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        mapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        return mapping;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about the usesuffixPatternMatch. Will try that. Do you have any inputs regarding the other point - Is this a security issue? Can we prevent browser from redisplaying the URL as entered?

Comment: I tested it and yes the URL is redisplayed but the <script> tag isn't interpreted so I don't see any security issue here.

Answer (score 7):

In current Spring Java config, there is a slightly easier way to configure the same thing:

```
@Configuration
public class DispatcherConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use Spring to request a mapping of that type (i.e. "/anything") Spring actually maps your controller to several URLs:

/welcome
/welcome.*
/welcome/

To prevent this - either be more specific when you RequestMapping (i.e. /welcome.htm ), or manually map the URL to controller in your Xml config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/welcome">YourControllerBean</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Cheers, Pete

Comment: Thanks for the response. But am already using annotation based request handler mapping and I cannot use ".htm" suffix :(

Answer (score 1):

You can also restrict this in the web.xml by mentioning the url pattern. Instead of giving "/*", you can mention "/*.htm" in your web.xml.

Something like

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/application/*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do that. The incoming request comes in the format of "/welcome?key=value" and not "/welcome.html". This has been done to mask the underlying technology.

Comment: Ohh ok..acceptable...but to me it doesn't reveal any underlying technology rather it specifies the url pattern though...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [useDefaultSuffixPattern](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html#setUseDefaultSuffixPattern%28boolean%29) property.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Also refer [URL Pattern Restricting in SPRING MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883192/url-pattern-restricting-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Spring framework 5.3 useDefaultSuffixPattern is deprecated and turned off by default. Spring upgrade notes, [section "Use of Path Extensions Deprecated in Spring MVC"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#upgrading-to-version-53)