# URL Pattern Restricting in SPRING MVC

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, url-mapping

My Spring Web MVC application has the following handler mapping in the Controller.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/something")
```

When request is sent to

> http://www.someURL.com/something

, it works fine and maps to correct controller  but,

`http://www.someURL.com/something.bak  or http://www.someURL.com/something.abc or http://www.someURL.com/something.abc.deff.xyz`  also works!!

I want to restrict this to just `http://www.someURL.com/something` and not to others.

`web.xml` defines the mappings as :-

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [useDefaultSuffixPattern](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html#setUseDefaultSuffixPattern%28boolean%29) property.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Hey This works thanks.But need to remove <mvc:annotation-driven> from servelt mapping xml.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above, refer to documentation below:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html

Method: setUseDefaultSuffixPattern()

Also go through similar queries asked below:
[How to change Spring MVC's behavior in handling url 'dot' character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135329/how-to-change-spring-mvcs-behavior-in-handling-url-dot-character)

Comment: Looks like MVC Annotation Driven and bean method does not work together. we have to remove MVC Annotation Driven for other to work.