# How do I restrict route extensions in @RequestMapping paths for Spring MVC controllers?

Tags: spring-mvc, routes, uri, controllers

I have a fairly simple task that I want to accomplish, but can't seem to find information for Spring MVC routing about it. I have a very simple controller that routes a path to a view:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/help")
public class HelpController {

    private static final String HELP = "help";

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String help(Model model, Locale locale) {
        model.addAttribute("locale", locale);
        return HELP;
    }
}
```

I would like to throw a 404 if *http://mysite.com/help.some.extension.is.entered*, but Spring seems to resolve the example to /help. The javadoc says that the @RequestMapping annotation is just a servlet URI mapping, but I thought /help means it needs to be an exact match. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For Spring 4 it's pretty easy to solve:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:path-matching suffix-pattern="false" />
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

So you still can use `mvc:annotation-driven` for your config.

Answer (score 0):

You can mention it in the @RequestMapping annotation

it is same as Servlet URL pattern only.

```
@Controller
public class HelpController {

    private static final String HELP = "help";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/help" method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String help(Model model, Locale locale) {
        model.addAttribute("locale", locale);
        return HELP;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "help/*" method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helpWithExtraWords() {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, this does not solve the problem because the route has /* in front of it. My goal is to return a 404 when /help.suffix is entered. Spring accepts the period character as a valid extension of /help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of is to configure your RequestMappingHandlerMapping explicitly to not consider suffixpaths, this way:

```
<bean name="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useSuffixPatternMatch" value="false"></property>
</bean>
```

However, if you have configured your Spring MVC using `mvc:annotation-driven`, this will not work, you will have to expand out the entire handlerAdapter definition, which is not that difficult to do, along these lines(this is not complete, you can look through `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser` for the entire definition):

```
<bean name="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
            <property name="conversionService" ref="conversionService"></property>
            <property name="validator">
                <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useSuffixPatternMatch" value="false"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I tried something very similar from a post on the springsource forums. It didn't seem to make a difference. http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?91379-RequestMapping-drops-requested-quot-file-quot-extension

Comment: That is strange @Roosh, this configuration works for me, can you confirm that you have completely removed `mvc:annotation-driven` and have only this handlerMapping. Also, can you tell me the version of Spring you are using - Spring 3.0.5 the configuration is different from what I have provided(this is for Spring 3.1+)

Comment: I'm using Spring 3.0.6. I did not remove my <mvc:annotation-driven> statement from the spring file. I'll try that and let you know if it works.

Comment: Yes, that should be the reason @Roosh, in Spring 3.0.6 the first line should be `<bean name="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">`

Answer (score 0):

With Spring 3.0.X You can use the [useDefaultSuffixPattern](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html#setUseDefaultSuffixPattern%28boolean%29) property.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
</bean>
```

You will need to remove `</mvc:annotation-driven>`

Refer [URL Pattern Restricting in SPRING MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883192/url-pattern-restricting-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: I started getting servlet exceptions when I removed <mvc:annotation-driven>. javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [com.myapp.controller.ResourceController@244a0a42]: Does your handler implement a supported interface like Controller?

Comment: @Roosh You should also use '<bean name="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAda‌​pter"> ' this will work!!