# SpringMVC /myproject/home.any_symbols acts like /myproject/home

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have a SpringMVC controller with mapping like this

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String showHomePage(Map<String, Object> model) {
    return "home";
}
```

So I can find the home page at /myproject/home.

But I also will be able to access this page by typing /myproject/home.any_set_of_symbols. How can I make the page accessible by only /myproject/home? The version of Spring Framework is 4.0.0

Comment: "But I also will be able to access this page by..." what makes you think that?

Comment: [Here][1] is a similar problem with solution


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887409/how-do-i-restrict-route-extensions-in-requestmapping-paths-for-spring-mvc-contr