# How to change spring request mapping to disallow url pattern with suffix

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 3.2 and deploying in Apache Tomcat 1.7x. My login url is `/web/login` but using url `/web/login.abc` where abc can be any text including space.

In both cases it is returning the same resource which I will like to avoid and return HTTP code 404.

Tried adding the below in **web.xml** but it did not help

```
`<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <beans:property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
</beans:bean>`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This config depends on the version you're using which you've omitted in your question. *Since Spring 4.0.3* the suffix properties are set on the `PathMatchConfigurer` class. As per [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-path-matching) the config should be under `mvc:annotation-driven`, e.g.

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:path-matching suffix-pattern="false" />
  </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

as explained in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/PathMatchConfigurer.html)

> Whether to use suffix pattern match `(".*")` when matching patterns to
>   requests. If enabled a method mapped to `"/users"` also matches to
>   `"/users.*"`.     The default value is **true**.

For *Spring 3.2* it should be

```
  <beans:bean id="handlerMapping"
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
      <beans:property name="useSuffixPatternMatch" value="false"/>
  </beans:bean>`
```

Also, if you're using the `mvc:annotation-driven` element in your config, take a note of Biju's answer from this question [How do I restrict route extensions in @RequestMapping paths for Spring MVC controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887409/how-do-i-restrict-route-extensions-in-requestmapping-paths-for-spring-mvc-contr)

Comment: thanks for your response. I should have clarified this in my post, we are using spring 3.2 as of now. Any suggestion on Spring 3.2 version?

Comment: I've added for Spring 3.2, but its from the top of my head. I'll try to verify this later, but it should be correct, let me know if its working for you.