# Spring webmvc controller accepts `.com/` but rejects `.com` in url with throwing 406 error

Tags: java, spring

I am new to `spring webmvc` plz bear with me and I am not able to post exactly what to ask due to my lack of understanding on this subject. All I can say is `spring mvc file extentions`.

- inherited `maven + spring webmvc 5.1.2.RELEASE` project
- deployed `mvn built` `fooapp.war` to `tomcat 8.5.58` on `linux` platform

The question I have is when I fire rest api call in a browser for the `/mail/{address}` endpoint.

**Case 1)**

Without `/` at the end of uri, it returns `http status 406 - The target resource does not have a current representation that would be acceptable to the user agent, according to the proactive negotiation header fields received in the request, and the server is unwilling to supply a default representation.`

```
http://localhost:<port>/fooapp/mail/john@bar.com
```

**Case 2)**

However with `/` at the end of uri, it returns proper response in `json` format.

```
http://localhost:<port>/fooapp/mail/john@bar.com/
```

I was not able to formulate a proper question to start with not understanding its cause but I did my best searching for a clue from `www`. I came to many threads but these caught my eyes:

- [How to change spring request mapping to disallow url pattern with suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610607/how-to-change-spring-request-mapping-to-disallow-url-pattern-with-suffix)
- [Spring MVC; avoiding file extension in url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399487/spring-mvc-avoiding-file-extension-in-url)

This is what I tried.

Frist replaced `/` with `/*` for `url-pattern` in the `web.xml`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>fooapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:fooapp.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fooapp</servlet-name>        
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

From the `fooapp.xml`, `<mvc:path-matching suffix-pattern="false"/>` is added.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:path-matching suffix-pattern="false"/>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

And the watered down version of `FooController.java`.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/mail/{address}")
public final class FooController {
    
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public String doSomething(
    @PathVariable("address") String address, HttpServletResponse response) {         
    // execute code...
    return josnData;
}
```

Not knowing what I am doing my attempts didn't change the outcome. Why `.com` vs `.com/` is treated differently? And how to get a proper response back with `.com`?

**update**

I may found a clue: [Spring does not ignore file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578742/spring-does-not-ignore-file-extension)
will give a try what it says.

With ^ suggestion, I was able to avoid `http status 406` however when the `FooController` consume `email address`, it chops off `.com` so that data associated with the eamil address is not returned.

The suggestion I tried was adding following content to `fooapp.xml`.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />

<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
</bean>
```

**Found a solution**

With this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-pathvariable-dot

By adding `mail/{address:.+}` in the controller along with ^ solution together fixed the problem.

Comment: I would try moving the endpoint specification, `"/mail/{address}"` from the class annotation to the method annotation.  I think what's happening is that it expects the method to add something to the url's path, hence the need to see the `/` at the end.

Comment: Ty @Steve for your time and advice on this. I've tried moving `/mail/{address}` to the method but unfortunately I am seeing same outcome in where `.com` is chopped off when the `FooController` consums full email address from a log file... I appreciate your advice though I am gradually understanding the cause of this problem..